# How do I retrieve list items from a sharepoint online site to another website?

Tags: sharepoint-online

I need to display the list items from a sharepoint online site to another website created using ASP.NET HTML.

Answer (score 1):

You could get the list items by REST API and httpclient.

For more detailed information, refer to the articles below.

[Complete basic operations using SharePoint REST endpoints.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/complete-basic-operations-using-sharepoint-rest-endpoints)

[Working with lists and list items with REST.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-lists-and-list-items-with-rest)

[Consume SharePoint Online REST service using .NET.](https://blog.vgrem.com/2015/04/04/consume-sharepoint-online-rest-service-using-net/)